# How can I get the next row value in a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, ta-lib

I'm a new Python user and I'm trying to learn this so I can complete a research project on cryptocurrencies. What I want to do is retrieve the value right after having found a condition, and retrieve the value 7 rows later in another variable.

I'm working within an Excel spreadsheet which has 2250 rows and 25 columns. By adding 4 columns as detailed just below, I get to 29 columns. It has lots of 0s (where no pattern has been found), and a few 100s (where a pattern has been found). I want my program to get the row right after the one where 100 is present, and return it's Close Price. That way, I can see the difference between the day of the pattern and the day after the pattern. I also want to do this for seven days down the line, to find the performance of the pattern on a week.

[Here's a screenshot of the spreadsheet to illustrate this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcUKo.png)

You can see -100 cells too, those are bearish pattern recognition. For now I just want to work with the "100" cells so I can at least make this work.

I want this to happen:

```
import pandas as pd
import talib
import csv
import numpy as np

my_data = pd.read_excel('candlesticks-patterns-excel.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)

df['Next Close'] = np.nan_to_num(0) #adding these next four columns to my dataframe so I can fill them up with the later variables#
df['Variation2'] = np.nan_to_num(0)
df['Next Week Close'] = np.nan_to_num(0)
df['Next Week Variation'] = np.nan_to_num(0)
df['Close'].astype(float)

for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
    str(row[7:23])
    if ((row[7:23]) == 100):
        nextclose = np.where(row[7:23] == row[7:23]+1)[0] #(I Want this to be the next row after having found the condition)#
    if (row.Index + 7 < len(df)):
        nextweekclose = np.where(row[7:23] == row[7:23]+7)[0] #(I want this to be the 7th row after having found the condition)#
    else:
        nextweekclose = 0
```

The reason I want these values is to later compare them with these variables:

```
variation2 = (nextclose - row.Close) / row.Close * 100
    nextweekvariation = (nextweekclose - row.Close) / row.Close * 100
    df.append({'Next Close': nextclose, 'Variation2': variation2, 'Next Week Close': nextweekclose, 'Next Week Variation': nextweekvariation}, ignore_index = true)
```

My errors come from the fact that I do not know how to retrieve the row+1 value, and the row+7 value. I have searched high and low all day online and haven't found a concrete way to do this. Whichever idea I try to come up with gives me either a **"can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"** error, or a **"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'close'"**. This second one I get when I try:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
    str(row[7:23])
    if ((row[7:23]) == 100):
        nextclose = df.iloc[row.Index + 1,:].close
    if (row.Index + 7 < len(df)):
        nextweekclose = df.iloc[row.Index + 7,:].close
    else:
        nextweekclose = 0
```

I would really love some help on this.
Using Jupyter Notebook.

### EDIT : FIXED

I have finally succeeded ! As it often seems to be the case with programming (yeah, I'm new here...), the mistakes were because of my inability to think outside the box. I was persuaded a certain part of my code was the problem, when the issues ran deeper than that.

Thanks to BenB and Michael Gardner, I have fixed my code and it is now returning what I wanted. Here it is.

```
import pandas as pd
import talib
import csv
import numpy as np
        
my_data = pd.read_excel('candlesticks-patterns-excel.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
        
        
#Creating my four new columns. In my first message I thought I needed to fill them up
#with 0s (or NaNs) and then fill them up with their respective content later. 
#It is actually much simpler to make the operations right now, keeping in mind 
#that I need to reference df['Column Of Interest'] every time.
    
df['Next Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)
df['Variation2'] = (((df['Next Close'] - df['Close']) / df['Close']) * 100)
df['Next Week Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-7)
df['Next Week Variation'] = (((df['Next Week Close'] - df['Close']) / df['Close']) * 100)
    
#The only use of this is for me to have a visual representation of my newly created columns#
print(df)
        
for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
    if 100 or -100 in row[7:23]:
        nextclose = df['Next Close']
            
    if (row.Index + 7 < len(df)) and 100 or -100 in row[7:23]:
            nextweekclose = df['Next Week Close']
        else:
            nextweekclose = 0
                
        variation2 = (nextclose - row.Close) / row.Close * 100
        nextweekvariation = (nextweekclose - row.Close) / row.Close * 100
        df.append({'Next Close': nextclose, 'Variation2': variation2, 'Next Week Close': nextweekclose, 'Next Week Variation': nextweekvariation}, ignore_index = True)
        
df.to_csv('gatherinmahdata3.csv')
```

Comment: ok lets look at this, `df['Close'].astype(float)` is not inline, this row does nothing, `str(row[7:23])` does as well nothing, and I cant understand what are you trying to do there, `if ((row[7:23]) == 100):` makes no sense, you want to compare elements 7:23 with a single integer? what is this supposed to do? You have not shown us your data so it is hard to guess. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Ruli you are right, this is pretty unclear as this is my first python project. I have edited my post to include a screenshot of the dataset. I have removed both of the things that "do nothing", I added them before when trying out tons of different things I saw on this website. Should've just put a # before them, sorry !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use `shift` to move the rows by the amount you want and then do your conditional calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Close': np.arange(8)})

df['Next Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)
df['Next Week Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-7)

df.head(10)

   Close  Next Close  Next Week Close
0      0         1.0              7.0
1      1         2.0              NaN
2      2         3.0              NaN
3      3         4.0              NaN
4      4         5.0              NaN
5      5         6.0              NaN
6      6         7.0              NaN
7      7         NaN              NaN

df['Conditional Calculation'] = np.where(df['Close'].mod(2).eq(0), df['Close'] * df['Next Close'], df['Close'])

df.head(10)

   Close  Next Close  Next Week Close  Conditional Calculation
0      0         1.0              7.0                      0.0
1      1         2.0              NaN                      1.0
2      2         3.0              NaN                      6.0
3      3         4.0              NaN                      3.0
4      4         5.0              NaN                     20.0
5      5         6.0              NaN                      5.0
6      6         7.0              NaN                     42.0
7      7         NaN              NaN                      7.0
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! I have used your `df['Next Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)`
`df['Next Week Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-7)` and it works wonders. I will be looking at the rest later because I do not understand what your Conditional Calculation line means.

Comment: The conditional line is just for demonstration purposes.  What it is doing is if the remainder of the `Close` row dived by 2  equals 0 then multiply the `Close` row by the `Next Close` row else just return the `Close` row.

Answer (score 2):

From your update it becomes clear that the first if statement checks that there is the value "100" in your row. You would do that with

```
if 100 in row[7:23]:
```

This checks whether the integer 100 is in one of the elements of the tuple containing the columns 7 to 23 (23 itself is not included) of the row.

If you look closely at the error messages you get, you see where the problems are:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

comes from

```
nextclose = np.where(row[7:23] == row[7:23]+1)[0]
```

row is a tuple and slicing it will just give you a shorter tuple to which you are trying to add an integer, as is said in the error message. Maybe have a look at the documentation of numpy.where and see how it works in general, but I think it is not really needed in this case.
This brings us to your second error message:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'close'

This is case sensitive and for me it works if I just capitalize the close to "Close" (same reason why Index has to be capitalized):

```
nextclose = df.iloc[row.Index + 1,:].Close
```

You could in principle use the shift method mentioned in the other reply and I would suggest it for easiness, but I want to point out another method, because I think understanding them is important for working with dataframes:

```
nextclose = df.iloc[row[0]+1]["Close"]
nextclose = df.iloc[row[0]+1].Close
nextclose = df.loc[row.Index + 1, "Close"]
```

All of them work and there are probably even more possibilities. I can't really tell you which ones are the fastest or whether there are any differences, but they are very commonly used when working with dataframes. Therefore, I would recommend to have a closer look at the documentation of the methods you used and especially what kind of data type they return. Hope that helps understanding the topic a bit more.

Comment: Thank you @BenB this was a great idea, so simple and yet I completely missed how if `100 in row[7:23]:` would solve my problem. I have edited my response to include the working code.